# How to get Model Object using its name from a variable in Laravel 5?

Tags: class, object, model, laravel-5

I am trying to get information from a model using its name which is sent as parameter from blade using ajax call.

```
$.get("{{ url('auditInformation')}}", {modelName: modelName,versions:versions,currentData:currentData[index]});
```

Now i need to retrieve information using **modelName** from a model.

So when i tried this:

```
$auditInfo=Input::all();
    $modelName=$auditInfo['modelName'];
    $values=$modelName::find(1);
```

I got this response ***Class 'Designation' not found***

But if i use

```
$modelName=new Designation();
    $values=$modelName::find(1);
```

then it shows data exactly what i want.

So i understand that this is all about **model ( class )**   object.

Is there any way to assign object to **$modelName** using **$auditInfo['modelName']** .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do that way, you should use the model's namespace.

For example, if the 'Destination' model's namespace is app\Destination, you should use like this :

```
$auditInfo=Input::all();
$appPrefix = 'app';
$modelName=$appPrefix . '\' . $auditInfo['modelName'];
$values=$modelName::find(1);
```

Comment: I think you would need to escape the backslash like so:

$modelName=$appPrefix . '\\' . $auditInfo['modelName'];

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working

```
$table_name = "App\Models\PeopleYouMayLikeModel";

$obj = $table_name::where($column_name_identifier_1, '=', $row_identifier_1)
                  ->where($column_name_identifier_2, '=', $row_identifier_2)->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

The single backslash between the **singe quote** is considered as an escape sequence so use **double backslash** is 100% work. For example

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $model_prefix="App\Models";
    $modal = $model_prefix.'\\'.$request->type;
    $modal::updateOrcreate(['users_id'=>session("user")->users_id],$request->all())->save();
    dd(Profile::all());
}
//Laravel 7.0
```